# How to display duplicates of an aggregated attribute in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query, where I am finding the maximum weight of different products in a table. Each product has a brand name and a Sku, and each brand name can have multiple sku's.

That query is:

```
select brand_name
, sku
, max(weight) 
from bc.PRODUCTS
group by BRAND_NAME, SKU
order by 1
```

I want to display only those brand_names who have return multiple rows in the above query.

My working query is:

```
select max(weight)
, sku
, brand_name
from bc.PRODUCTS
group by BRAND_NAME, sku
having count(brand_name) > 1
order by 3
;
```

Yet that does not return any results.

I am very much a beginner, so any help would be appreciated.
;

Comment: please edit the question and show a sample table and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

We can subquery your current query and include the count across each brand:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT BRAND_NAME, SKU, MAX(weight) AS MAX_WEIGHT,
           SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY bra BRAND_NAME) cnt
    FROM bc.PRODUCTS
    GROUP BY BRAND_NAME, SKU
)

SELECT BRAND_NAME, SKU, MAX_WEIGHT
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1;
```